# How to set day intervals in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need assistance setting up the query below to run on the daily.

```
select dbo.Diario.Fecha, dbo.Diario.Descripcion, dbo.paf.Numero, dbo.paf.Version, dbo.paf.Nombre
from dbo.Diario
left join dbo.paf on dbo.Diario.Numero = dbo.paf.Numero
where dbo.Diario.Fecha is not null and
dbo.Diario.Fecha > '2019-01-01'
order by dbo.Diario.Fecha ASC;
```

Comment: Please read the guide to asking a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How do you set up a SSRS query to run on the daily ?

Comment: Sorry that doesn't make sense - do you want to schedule a report to run daily? e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/subscriptions-and-delivery-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Have you designed a report to consume the output of the query above? If so, just set a schedule on the report to run once at desired time and do whatever you want.. email.. save to directory etc.